# Что надо сделать в aiogrm ,чтобы он смог посчитать числа?

Tags: python

Вот код который я пытался сделать:

```
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
bot = Bot(token="token")
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
@dp.message_handler(commands="start")
async def number10(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Введите первое число")
async def number20(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Введите второе число")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Задумка такая:
Для начала нажимаешь на /start
Потом тебе приходить сообщение: Введите первое число
Ты вводишь ,например, число 5
Потом тебе приходить:Введите второе число
Вводишь 5
Потом: Введите арифметическое действие(+,-,*,/)
Ты вводишь +
И бот тебе считает ответ
Помогите пожалуйста!!!

Comment: пример от разрабов https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/blob/dev-2.x/examples/finite_state_machine_example.py

Comment: это не то ,там другое чет ,а мне нужен пример калькулятора

Comment: А типо нельзя забрать ввод пользователя и сложить? И еще, не показывайте токен бота

Comment: Декоратор действует только на одну функцию - перед которой он записан. Вторая функция у вас никогда не вызовется. Нужен именно конечный автомат (finite state machine, то что вам по ссылке в первом комментарии дали), чтобы после запроса первого числа шел запрос второго числа (перешло из состояния 1 в состояние 2).